# How to find max value from a list of numbers stored as string in a Jinja template?

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a list of integers stored in a list. Apparently it is stored as string in the datastore. So my current list of integers are as:

```
price = ['31412', '12300', '23000']
```

I want to get the highest number from the list.

```
{% for i in price %}
highest price is: {{ i | max }}
{% endfor %}
```

Expected output:

```
highest price is: 31412
```

What I get is:

```
highest price is: 4
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Are you sure you don't get `highest price is: 4  highest price is: 3  highest price is: 3`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `jinja2`, but you can convert every string to integer first with list comprehension and find the max of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first convert each string in the list to an integer before finding the maximum.

According to my understanding of the documentation you should be able to use the [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) filter like so:

```
highest price is: {{ price | map('int') | max }}
```

This should be equivalent to the Python code `max(map(int, price))`.

You don't need a `for` construct. The `max` filter already implicitly loops over the `price` list.